# Warp quadrangle with for corner points to rectangular 2D image with given aspect ratio

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-image, apple-vision

I want to build a business card scanner with `Vision` API.
So I'm performing a [`VNDetectRectanglesRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vndetectrectanglesrequest) with specific rectangle constraints for the business card format (which has a fixed ratio).

As a result of this I'm getting a [`VNRectangleObservation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnrectangleobservation) object back which contains the for corner points for the rectangle. This is mostly a rectangle in 3D space but just a quadrangle in 2D because the physical object can be captured slightly from the side for example.

Now I want to cut out the image with those 4 corner points and warp/distort it into a flat rectangular like the iOS notes app does it when you capture a document.

[image]

I don't need any AR like prediction of the document aspect ratio as it is fixed (by the business card format).

How can I do this in Swift using internal libraries e.g. `CoreGraphics` or `CoreImage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found this [very similar question with a excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47178521/4846592) pointing to [`CIPerspectiveCorrection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPerspectiveCorrection) which does exactly what I need: Accepting an image and for points to transform it to a 2D rectangle.

*I won't delete my question because the titles are very different and my question could lead people to the solution :].*

Comment: If you managed to animate it, how did you do it?

Comment: I didn't. I faked it with a fast crossfade/scale animation^^. But if you do, let us know :-)